# Graphene characteristics

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory, graphene

I am trying to understand the physics of graphene and was unable to understand its I-V characteristics. Could anyone please explain it in simple terms. I have gone through the papers online but couldn't get much out of it.[image: transfer characteristics]

[image: output characteristics]

My question: There are both electrons and holes in graphene. But for positive $V_{ds}$ (drain-to-source applied voltage), there is electron conduction. How does ambipolar conduction happen?

Comment: Please ask a _specific_ question. What exactly, do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: @josephh what I understand is: Actually, there are both electrons and holes in graphene. But for positive Vds, there is electron conduction. but how does ambipolar conduction happen?

Comment: I have added your comment to the question, where it should have been originally.